# ActionMailerNext double dot or double full stop

Tags: email, razor, model-view-controller, console-application, actionmailer

I am using ActionMailerNext Standalone v3.2 in a console application. I populate the model from the database and send the email using email template with IEmailResult. But it replaces a dot with double dot at random places. If the email contains an url to an image say image.png, it appears as image..png. It sometimes happens with full stops at the end of the sentence as well. Has someone come across something like this before or is this something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to specify the MessageEncoding property in ActionMailerNext.Standalone.RazorMailerBase.MailAttributes which has solved the issue.